# PowerShell - List Folders Beginning With A + (Plus} Sign

Tags: directory, special-characters, powershell-4.0

I'm having a strange problem. If I have any folders in a path beginning with a + Sign,
eg +Folder1 and +Folder2 then

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $pwd -Directory
```

will list them with the leading plus sign if the read mode bit is set (+Folder1, +Folder2), and without the the +sign if the read mode bit is not set (is blank) (Folder1, Folder2). Does anyone know how to consistently list them correctly (showing the leading +sign) as I need to handle them differently them based upon this first character, and it doesnt show up in a stored string either (`$Folders = GCI -Directory`).

Thanks for the response. I am Running Windows 10 Pro.
A quick way to see the 5 File/Folder Mode Flags is to run
Get-ChildItem *; Pause. (from a small Powershell script) In the window that opens up, the leftmost column shows the Mode settings. This problem only applies to folders - not to files - When the read-mode bit is set to r, I get a different result than when it is blank. I noticed some of my folders had no read flag set and others were set, so I am getting inconsistent results when I run my script.

Comment: What do you mean by "_the read mode bit_"? Please [edit] your question and elaborate your [mcve].

Comment: I assume that by "read mode bit" you mean the readonly flag. I am not seeing this issue, I get the folders either way. Which OS are you running? Please